# ¿Como puedo mapear un VISTA o un PROCEDIMIENTO ALMACENADO de una base de datos sql server con Hibernate en java se?

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, jpa

¿Como puedo mapear un VISTA o un PROCEDIMIENTO ALMACENADO de una base de datos sql server con Hibernate en Java SE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se puede mapear una Vista, pero no un Procedimiento Almacenado.

### Mapear una Vista con Hibernate

Las Vistas, en general, son mapeadas de la misma manera que las tablas. Solo hay que definir una entidad que mapee la vista con su nombre específico y el de sus columnas.

La diferencia radica en que una vista no debe ser modificada por Hibernate, y esto se logra con la anotación específica de Hibernate `@Inmutable`.

Ejemplo:

```
@Entity
@Talbe(name = "vista_Factura") // <--- nombre de la vista en la base de datos
@Immutable
public class VistaFactura {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
   private Long id;

   @Column
   private BigDecimal totaBruto;

   @Column
   private BigDecimal totalImpuestos;

   @Column
   private BigDecimal totalNeto;

   @Column
   private String observaciones;

   @Column
   private Instant fechaCreacion;

   //...
}
```

La anotación `@Inmutable` le dice a Hibernate que ignore todos los cambios en esta entidad, pero puedes usarla para obtener datos de la base de datos.

```
List<VistaFactura> listaFactura = em.createQuery("SELECT v FROM VistaFactura v", VistaFactura.class).getResultList();
```

En resumen, debes tratar a la vista como una tabla normal solo que no puedes insertarle/actualizarle valores.

### Llamar un Procedimiento Almacenado con Hibernate

Aunque no se pueden mapear, se pueden hacer llamados nativos SQL a procedimientos almacenados usando el método `createSQLQuery()` de una `Session` de Hibernate.

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery("CALL  nombreProcedimientoAlmacenado").addEntity(MiEntidad.class);
```

Y si el procedimiento almacenado requiere parámetros:

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery("CALL nombreProcedimientoAlmacenado(:parametro1)")
  .addEntity(MiEntidad.class)
  .setParameter("parametro1","valor");
```

Y los resultados se pueden obtener así:

```
List<MiEntidad> listaMisEntidades = query.list();
```

También es posible llamar Procedimientos almacenados con anotaciones, `@NamedStoredProcedureQuery` para procedimientos almacenados y `@StoredProcedureParameter` para los parámetros, pero no me extenderé más en el tema.

Comment: Gracias por el aporte, una consulta y ¿ como obtengo los nombre de la columnas de mi tabla sin usar entidades ?

Comment: ¿Con Hibernate? ¿Qué quieres hacer exactamente?